# How to add the "play again?" feature for java

Tags: java

Im making a guessing game for my class and I need some help for adding a "play again" feature at the end of the game when you've guessed the right number:

```
public class GuessingGame
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int numtoguesses = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        int counter = 0;
        int guess = -1;

        while (guess != numtoguesses)
        {
            System.out.print ("|" + numtoguesses + "|" + "Guess the right number: ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            counter = counter + 1;

            if (guess == numtoguesses)
                System.out.println ("YOU WIN MOFO!");
            else if (guess < numtoguesses)
                System.out.println ("You're to cold!");
            else if (guess > numtoguesses)
                System.out.println ("You're to hot!");
        }

        System.out.println ("It took you " + counter + " guess(es) to get it correct");     
    }   
}
```

Comment: Enclose the game logic itself in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach would be to move the code you've written into a function

```
   public void play() { 
   ...
   }
```

and from `main` do something like:

```
   do { 
      play();
      playAgain = promptUser;
   } while(playAgain);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put another while loop over everything.

```
boolean playing = true;

while(playing) {
  while(guess != numtoguesses) { // All code }

  System.out.println("Do you wish to play again? Y/N");
  String answer = input.nextLine();
  playing = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
  count = 0;
  guess = -1;
}
```

Everything together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numtoguesses = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
    int counter = 0;
    int guess = -1;
    boolean playing = true;

    while(playing) {

      while (guess != numtoguesses) {
        System.out.print ("|" + numtoguesses + "|" + "Guess the right number: ");
        guess = input.nextInt();
        counter = counter + 1;

        if (guess == numtoguesses)
            System.out.println ("YOU WIN MOFO!");
        else if (guess < numtoguesses)
            System.out.println ("You're to cold!");
        else if (guess > numtoguesses)
            System.out.println ("You're to hot!");
      }
    }

    System.out.println ("It took you " + counter + " guess(es) to get it correct"); 

    System.out.println("Do you wish to play again? Y/N");
    String answer = input.nextLine();
    playing = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
    count = 0;
    guess = -1;   
    numtoguesses = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1; 
}
```

You should extract this in a few methods, but I'll leave that up to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options I can think about. The quickest:

-- place all the code between lines `int numtoguesses = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;` (inclusive) and end of main method inside an infinite loop
-- at the end of your current code block, add an interogation to the user, asking him whether he/she wants to play again (you can define a convention for the pressed keys); this part is placed also inside the infinite loop
-- if he/she doesn't want to, break the (outer) infinite loop