# How do I implement a "play again" feature in my java using a while or do-while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while, inputmismatchexception

I know this same thing has been asked before but I am having a lot of trouble getting this guy to work. EDIT: it now seems to just keep running indefinitely. I no longer get an error but the code will just keep running until I stop it.

And now for my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Guess2
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner outScan = new Scanner (System.in);
            boolean input = true;
            while (input == true) {

            System.out.println(
                    "Gimme a number, any number. This number will be the maximum\n"
                            + " in a range of numbers. Your goal is to guess\n"
                            + " the number that I have picked at random"
                            + " within this range. Then, enter how many"
                            + " guesses you would like to receive.");
            int max = scan.nextInt();
            int meGuess = scan.nextInt();
            // Round whatever random number is generated
            double randomNumber =
                    (int) Math.round((max * Math.random()) + 1);
            randomNumber = (int) randomNumber;
            System.out.println("Alright now guess which number I picked.");
            int numGuess = 0;
            while (numGuess <= meGuess)
                {
                    int guess = scan.nextInt();
                    if (guess < randomNumber)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Too low, my friend.");
                            numGuess++;
                        } else if (guess == randomNumber)
                        {
                            numGuess++;
                            System.out.print(
                                    "Wowee Zowee! You got it right! AI "
                                            + "will absolutely never sufficiently replace "
                                            + "human intellect.\n"
                                            + "It only took you "
                                            + numGuess);
                            if (numGuess == 1)
                                {
                                    System.out.println(" try.");
                                } else
                                {
                                    System.out.println(" tries.");
                                }
                            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Y/N");
                            String answer = outScan.nextLine();
                            input = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
                            numGuess = 0;
                            meGuess = 0;
                            max = 0;
                        } else if (guess > randomNumber)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Too high, buddy.");
                            numGuess++;
                        }
                    if (numGuess > meGuess)
                        {
                            System.out
                                    .println("Sorry buddy, you used up more"
                                            + " guesses than you told me to give you."
                                            + " Maybe next time.");
                            System.out.println("Do you want to play again? Y/N");
                            String answer = outScan.nextLine();
                            input = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
                            numGuess = 0;
                            meGuess = 0;
                            max = 0;
                        }

                }
            scan.close();
            outScan.close();
        }}



}
```

Some background

1. I am able to get this game to play at least once through with no problem. For some reason, sometimes the correct answer for the number to be guessed is +1 out of range (for example, I do max 3, guesses 5, and the correct answer ends up being 4 somehow). I am also allowed more guesses than I said I wanted. This is not my priority and I will fix that later, but I would like help with that. I'm sure I'm just overlooking something.

   2. Lastly, this is only one way I have tried to do this, by putting a while loop at the top of the main function. I have also tried to put the bulk of the code into a different function, as per the recommendation of [another poster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20228973/4821779), and use a do-while loop, but that was also to no avail. Maybe I did not understand the specificities of how to do something like that, but I would get a similar, if not the same error.

I have put a bit of effort into resolving this problem myself and I hope this question meets community standards. I will be finishing this up myself later today so either way I'll be working on it but I would appreciate any help I could get. Thank you.

Comment: Please look at [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo). This is likely causing or contributing to your problem.

Comment: Any place you have `int max = scan.nextInt();` any place you call `scan.nextInt()` follow it *immediately* with a call to `scan.nextLine();` to handle the end-of-line token.

Comment: **AND** you're closing your Scanner ***within*** the while loop! Don't do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems:

- You're not handling the end of line token properly when getting ints from the Scanner. Follow any call to `scan.nextInt()` with `scan.nextLine();` to handle and swallow this token
- Your closing your Scanner ***within*** your while loop, so it is dead when the while loop repeats and no input is obtainable. Put that code to close *outside* the while loop.
- You also need to reset your counter
- You should only use **one** Scanner based on `System.in`
- You're asking if you want to play again within the inner while loop which makes no sense. You need ask and get this information from within the outer while loop
- Most important is that you need to learn how to debug. Please check out this great reference: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)